# How can I use .split() to split a string of different space amounts?

Tags: java, split

Say you have the string

```
"A  B     C  D"
```

How can I used Java .split() in order to split this into an array separating with the 2 and 5 spaces?

The array would hold {A,B,C,D}

Comment: `str.split(" +")`

Comment: `"A  B     C  D".split("\\s+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below one:

```
"A  B     C  D".split("\\s+")

\\s+ means one or more space.
```